# Django query extended user model for authentication

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-views

I have an issue with authentication in django with an extended user model.
I want the user to authenticate with a customer number, a username and a password.

This are my models:

```
class Mandant(models.Model):
    Mandant_id = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key= True)
    Mandant_accn= models.CharField('Kundennummer', max_length=10)
    Mandant_name = models.CharField('Bezeichnung', max_length=200)
    Mandant_street = models.CharField('Straße', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Mandant_zip = models.CharField('PLZ', max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    Mandant_city = models.CharField('Ort', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Mandant_iban = models.CharField('IBAN', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Mandant_bic = models.CharField('BIC', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Mandant_ustid = models.CharField('UstID', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    Mandant_vf = models.DateTimeField('Gültig von', default=now)
    Mandant_vu = models.DateTimeField('Gültig bis', null=True, blank=True)
    Mandant_ia = models.DateTimeField('Hinzugefügt am', auto_now=True)
    Mandant_deleted = models.BooleanField('Gelöscht', default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Mandant_name

    class Meta:
        app_label ="meas"
        ordering = ['Mandant_ia']

class Meas_User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mandant_id = models.ForeignKey(Mandant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I extended the django default user model with an onetoonefield in my Meas_User model.

Now I tried to write a login view for my app users. 
But I dont get how to do a query like the in the following SQL statement

```
SELECT User, Mandant FROM [User] INNER JOIN (Mandant INNER JOIN MEAS_user ON Mandant.Mandant_ID = MEAS_user.Mandant_ID) ON User.ID = MEAS_user.user_ID WHERE (((User.username)="lorem Ipsum") AND ((Mandant.Customer_Number)="1234"));
```

I tried the select_related() function, but without success.
My desired result is to get the user of the mandant - identified by the entered customer number - (if applicable) to check the entered password in the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly something like this would work:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Mandant, Meas_User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def loginview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mandant_accn = request.POST['mandant_accn']
        password =  request.POST['password']
        mandant = Mandant.objects.get(mandant_accn=mandant_accn)
        meas_user = Meas_User.objects.get(meas_user=mandant.Mandant_id)
        username = User.objects.get(pk=meas_user.user_id).username
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
```

Haven't fully tested it, but you ask for the accountnumber in the template, send it to the view, find the corresponding Mandant, from there find the corresponding User and then use the standard login.

It's a bit of a complicated setup you have, with user information spread over three models (standard Django user model, Meas_User, Mandant). It might be simpler to just have two models. I have good experience with a custom user model, extending AbstractUser class from Django. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project.